# App Rejected due to SMS_SEND permision I have selected default handler?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

App uses SEND_SMS permission to send sms for this i have selected default handler , ad google reject my app so how to resolve this issue

[image]

Comment: What does your app do? Why does it need SMS access?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google

> If your app requests the use of high-risk or sensitive permissions (for example, SMS or Call Log), you may be required to complete the Permissions Declaration Form and receive approval from Google Play.

[Permissions declaration](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?visit_id=637850965469677030-4243776335&rd=1)

[How to complete the Permissions declaration form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?visit_id=637850965469677030-4243776335&rd=1#app_access)

> Incase you are still stuck, you can try this
> If your app need to read sms for SMS-based user verification / OTP
> verification please use [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) which does not needed any
> sms permission and your app can still read SMS for OTP verification.

Comment: bro then how can i request sms permission

Comment: check the comment

Comment: i have also submitted this form

Comment: I have modify the comment incase you want to use SMS Retriever API